# My login code not working. what am i doing wrong

Tags: php

I get error when i try to login; but my code look fine after have gone through it.. is there anyting am not doing right. please help with this. after checking the code i notice it dosnt execute from ***if (isset($_POST['submit'])){.***

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            //form has been submitted1

            $uname  = trim($_POST['uname']);
            $upass  = trim($_POST['upass']);
            //$utype    = trim($_POST['utpye']);
            $h_upass = sha1($upass);
            if($uname == ''){   
                echo 'Username or Password Not Registered! Contact Your administrator...';
            }elseif($upass == ''){  
                echo 'Username or Password Not Registered! Contact Your administrator...';

            }else{

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname`='". $uname ."' and `u_pass`='". $h_upass ."'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die;
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                if ($numrows == 1){
                    $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $found_user['users_name'];
                    $_SESSION['usersname'] = $found_user['uname'];
                    $_SESSION['userpass'] = $found_user['u_pass'];
                    $_SESSION['usertype'] = $found_user['utype'];
            ?>  <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Welcome! <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?> your are successfully logged in.");
                    window.location = "index.php";
                </script>
            <?php


                }else{
                    echo 'Username or Password Not Registered! Contact Your administrator...';

                }

            }   
        }else{

            $uname  = "";
            $upass  = "";
            $utype  = "";
        }

    ?>
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="login.php">


<table class="app_table">

    <tr>
        <th> <div class="_title">Welcome Users::</div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">
            <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="_label">Username :: </td>
                        <td>
                         <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"  class="txtbox" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="_label">Password :: </td>
                        <td>
                         <input type="password" name="upass" id="upass"  class="txtbox" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>                    
                       <td align="Right">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="seacrh" value="Log in"/>

                        </td>
                       </td>
                  </tr>


            </table>    
        </td>
    </tr>       
</table>

</div>
</form>


    </table>

<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Show the form code. Looks like a field isn't being posted with the name `submit`.

Comment: sha1("") will return a value wether its empty or not, so do a check if it is set for the password **before** doing a sha1 hash, further your code is VERY vlunerable to SQL injections, try looking at using something like prepared statements or mysqli

Comment: Am actually new to php.. can you help in modifying my code?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! Try to learn PDO or use MySQLi.

Comment: @UmarE.Shaibu [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26844025/edit)

Comment: <td class="_label">Username :: </td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"  class="txtbox" />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="_label">Password :: </td>
      <td>
       <input type="password" name="upass" id="upass"  class="txtbox" />
      </td>
     </tr>
    
     
     <tr>     
        <td align="Right">
      <td>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="seacrh" value="Log in"/>
       
      </td>
        </td>
      </tr>

Comment: When dealing with passwords, I recommend you read and consider the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that password is stored encrypted? If not then change this line too:

```
$h_upass = sha1($upass);
```

to

```
$h_upass = $upass;
```

Comment: thanks alot.. it worked.. the password was not encrypted...

Answer (score 1):

1. You should send the form exactly to this PHP script.

   `<form action="script.php">`
2. Be sure you are using HTTP method POST

   `<form action="script.php" method="POST">`
3. Don't ignore errors, add it at least to output for the first version:

   `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`
4. Be sure what you have 'u_name' and 'u_pass' inputs in your form and you didn't misspell its names + your Submit button named "submit"

Comment: You've covered all bases, apart from the very open SQL injection. Nonetheless, +1

Comment: i just attached the form code to it

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line :

```
if ($numrows == 1){
```

to

```
if ($numrows){
```